# Dynamic ng-model for input AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem. When I use static template on render page

```
<form name="AddArticle" ng-submit="addArticle()" class="form add-article">
   <input type="text" value="first" init-from-form  ng-model="article.text[0]" />
   <input type="text" value="second" init-from-form  ng-model="article.text[1]" />
</form>
```

And when I do submit form, I get data:

```
{text : {0: "first", 1: "second"}}
```

But I have dynamic moment. By clicking I add dynamic `input`

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $('.form').append('<input ng-model="article.info" init-from-form type="text" />');
})
```

Ok. All appended, but by submit I still get data without dynamic input.

Tell me please, how to get all fields form???

Comment: Why not just have the form you are appending already in the document but have it hidden with `ng-if` ?

Comment: because this info I get through autocomplete and by click i add input with value that I must use in `ng-model`, i cant add this immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number one, don't mix jQuery like that when you can use angular. Try something like this:

view

```
  <form name="AddArticle" ng-submit="addArticle()" class="form add-article">
    <p ng-repeat="object in data track by $index">
      <input type="text" ng-model="object.text" />
    </p>
  </form>
  <button ng-click="addInput()">
    add
  </button>
  {{data}}
</div>
```

controller

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.addInput = function() {
      $scope.data.push({});
    }
  })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pntd3kaf/